# Have disabled Automatic Updates. Which Windows 8/8.1 Updates are Necessary and Which Can I Skip?

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

Have disabled Automatic Updates. Which Windows 8/8.1 Updates are Necessary and Which Can I Skip?
The List below includes all my copied updates. Thanks so much!

```
*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8.1 and 
Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3122651)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8.1 and 
Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3127222)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8.1 and 
Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3135985)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8.1 and 
Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3142045)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8.1 and 
Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3163247)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8.1 and 
Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB3072307)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8.1 and 
Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB3074545)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8.1 and 
Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB3097992)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 for 
Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3097997)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on 
Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 x64-based Systems (KB3023222)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on 
Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 x64-based Systems (KB3074228)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on 
Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 x64-based Systems (KB3074548)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 on 
Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 x64-based Systems (KB3098779)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 8.1 
and Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3122654)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 8.1 
and Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3127226)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 8.1 
and Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3135994)

*Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 8.1 
and Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3163291)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3019978)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3022777)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3023266)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3042058)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3046017)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3055642)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3061512)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3071756)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3075220)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3076895)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3076949)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3078601)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3082089)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3083992)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3084135)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3086255)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3092601)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3108381)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3109094)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3109103)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3109560)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3110329)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3121461)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3121918)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3123479)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3124280)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3126434)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3126587)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3126593)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3138910)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3138962)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3139398)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3139914)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3139940)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3146723)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3146963)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3149090)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3159398)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3161949)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3161958)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3164033)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3164035)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3169704)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3170455)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3172727)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3172729)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3177108)

*Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3178034)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB2976978)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3000850)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3013531)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3013538)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3013791)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3015696)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3020370)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3029606)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3033446)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3034348)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3037924)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3038002)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3038936)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3043812)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3044673)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3045717)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3045719)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3045992)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3046480)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3046737)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3047254)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3048043)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3053863)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3054169)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3054256)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3055343)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3056347)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3059316)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3060383)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3060793)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3061493)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3063843)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3064059)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3077715)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3078405)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3078676)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3079318)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3080149)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3091297)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3092627)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3095108)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3095701)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3096433)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3099834)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3100473)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3100919)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3100956)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3103696)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3103699)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3109976)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3115224)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3118401)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3121255)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3121261)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3123242)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3126030)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3126033)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3128650)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3133681)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3133690)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3133924)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3134815)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3136019)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3137725)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3137728)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3138602)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3140185)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3140219)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3140222)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3140234)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3140786)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3147071)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3162835)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3172614)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3173424)

*Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3182203)
```

Comment: I've been waiting for an opportunity to use the expression "fractally wrong", and here it is!

Comment: Go through each patch and determine which patches fix vulnerabilities you care about.

Comment: I've voted to close as opinion based. But I could have chosen too broad. Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: "I've been waiting for an opportunity to use the expression "fractally wrong", and here it is!" – ChrisA 1 hour ago <-warrants further explanation. 
"Go through each patch and determine which patches fix vulnerabilities you care about." – Ramhound 59 mins ago <--Positive & appreciative.
"I've voted to close as opinion based. But I could have chosen too broad. Please also read How do I ask a good question? and What types of questions should I avoid asking?." – DavidPostill 53 mins ago <-- This one, unimportant. There is no such thing as a wrong or right question. This we learn growing up.

Comment: ChrisA, Your comment is unwarranted to someone asking for help on something they don't quite understand. I know some about computers, fixing older PCs to natural state and REM String Programming yet I am lost when over 100 Updates come at me at one time. Sry to disappoint you wanting to use the insult. Def not me by far. "The state of being wrong at every conceivable scale of resolution. That is, from a distance, a fractally wrong person's worldview is incorrect; and furthermore, if you zoom in on any small part of that person's worldview, that part is just as wrong as the whole worldview."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think all updates are necessary, as Microsoft and Windows have a conception of "Optional Updates" which is disabled by default, unless you activate them by checking, marking up the square in some windows of Windows Update application.

But, here in your list, you have, Security and [NET Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) updates, and it can be told that you use 64 edition of Windows.

Basically, all of the updates also note their ID, or KB and seven numbers, which stand for Knowledge Base.

I suggest to search google for that ID and get information from Microsoft Knowledge Base for specific updates of interest.

Or shortly, you can simply put (append) the number ID into the following URL `support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/` eg [KB3122651](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3122651)

PS

By the way you inspired me to write the following script

```
@echo off
color a
set /p number="KB Number: "
start firefox https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/%number%
```

Save it as a `.bat` file (my suggestion being as `KnowledgeBase.bat`) and execute

It prompts for the number and accepts input when executed opening the related page on Microsoft Knowledge Base

PPS

It's written for Firefox, but you can replace the word with `iexplore` to open the links with the native Internet Explorer

Comment: As a college graduate I've always been told there is no such thing as a wrong, right or stupid question, lol. Here, I asked this because some of these Updates are years old and just came to me. I do not believe all are necessary. I do thank you for the comment inputs and thank you Chinggis6 and  Ramhound because yours are most helpful. I will search the KB's and see which are needed. I do not use Firefox, prefer Chrome and IE sucks. Getting all of these updates at one time is quite a lot to handle w/o knowing what each is for. Thank you for responding

Comment: Chinggis6, Awesome on the script. Glad I could inspire! :)

Comment: Thank you for positive feedback, I've added another, non-interactive version of the script worthy to look at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chinggis6/d78ye5dj/3/).